# Format android to join internal memory partitions?

Tags: rom-flashing, storage, partitions

I have searched around the net but not really finding exact problems nor solution related to mine.

I have a tablet which should have 8gb of internal memory but the problem is that it have divided memory onto 2 partitions as data storage and internal storage and i have lack of space on my data storage as its only 1gb while other partition uses rest of the internal storage.

So i cant install any more apps as my data storage is full while second partition is almost empty.

I have actually tried to flash emmc and new android but i got the same partition sizes.

My device is BlueBerry Netcat M-28, this should be rebranded chinese Cube tablet as i know. Anyway the model is from 2014 and uses:

Android 4.2.2
Baseband version MOLY.WR8.W1315
Kernel version 3.4.5 build Jan 2014 HKT(i guess this is hong kong time)

Mediatek ARM Dual Core MT8312 1.2GHz

Mount points in the screenshot below

[image]
<sup>Click on the image to enlarge</sup>

Just for the note:
I don't know much about android except that it's based on linux, at least the same kernel? But i do know my way around the linux, still android is unfamiliar to me. I had a same problem with space on my mobile phone Nokia N900 which runs on linux maemo, the phone have 32gb memory which was divided into 2gb and 26gb and 2gb was not enough. But on Nokia there was no problem, i was easily able to find flash tools, new firmware, modified kernel. It was just needed to ,modify file with hex editor and flash emmc with new settings od 8gb and 20gb partitions.

Why isn't possible something like this on tablet too?

Comment: What device & ROM (or Android Version) are you using?

Comment: As far as I know, the applications, app data and internal storage are present in the /data partition. So, space will be shared by both app data & internal storage. Maybe your device model is somewhat **old** I guess, in which app data & internal storage are different partitions.

Comment: I updated my question with the info you asked. I read about in the net that it's possible that this is because android 4.2 version, in later versions 4.4 devices have one big internal partition. At least that's on my brother's phone lenovo.

Comment: Is your phone rooted?
Is there a custom recovery for your phone?

Comment: It's rooted, i unlocked it with some app from google store, i can't remember, and there is only basic backup restore app that came pre installed from android. I don't care about losing data, i don't keep anything important on the phone and i copied all the photos to pc already. I am just worried not to brick it in process.

Comment: Is there a custom recovery installed?

Comment: Nope, i don't have any recovery installed.

Comment: since  I don't know this device I CAN'T TELL FORE SURE ,is the data and internal storage on the same physical partition ? and is app2sd an option for you (note app2sd is not link2sd) it when you mount data folder on another partition ,any way can you please post the output of the command "mount" on you device ?

Comment: As i noticed app2sd doesn't do nothing more than moving some apps to second partition. But in that case not only that app lose some of their functionality like notifications, some apps don't want to start anymore if i move them. I will update my question with screenshot of mount command so you can take a look

Comment: from the mount output ,I can tell that the /data and the sdcard are not on the same physical partition (/system /cache and  /data are on the same parttion) ,so merging data and sdcard is impossible why ? because they are not on the same physical device for example you can't merge 2 partitions from two different physical hard drives on a pc ,your best option here is app2sd (the deep one which requires a root , init.d and system can mount rw ) if you are open to the option I can post a more detailed answer

Comment: Wait i understand that these are different partitions, but you are telling me that those are even different hardware inside the tablet, that i have 2 different memories? I think it's only one emmc inside divided into partitions and storage/sdcard0 is only mount point to partition. At least that was the case on my Nokia N900 i had before. If you think link2sd would solve my problem i am up for trying the solution if you post it. Thanks.

Comment: An Advanced Solution: Use the 'parted' binary in the updater-script (to format your partitions as required (check the manual for usage)) of a flashable zip and flash it from a custom recovery. Then edit the boot.img's ramdisk accordingly to create the necessary symlinks and flash the new boot.img and try.. (I don't know if there's a custom recovery for your device.. And somehow try to get the boot.img .. Make sure you have flashable firmware for your device if something goes wrong)